# SMTP Exception handling

Tags: java, exception, smtp, jakarta-mail, liferay-6

I'm developing a code to send mail in Liferay...
The probleme here is that I want to send an error message

```
portletRequest.setAttribute("mailError", new String("smobile.error.mail"))
```

when the mail Server ( SMTP) is down..

Here is the source code.

```
try {
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));

    mailMessage.setSubject(subjectTemplate);
    mailMessage.setBody(bodyTemplate);
    mailMessage.setHTMLFormat(true);
    mailMessage.setTo(new InternetAddress(toEmail));

    // Send Mail
    MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(mailMessage);
    _log.info("Confirmation email sent with success!");
} catch(MessagingException me) {
    if (me.getNextException() instanceof SocketException) {
        _log.warn("EMAIL ENGINE ERROR");
        portletRequest.setAttribute("mailError", new String("smobile.error.mail"));
    }
    throw new MailEngineException(me);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JavaMail FAQ entry might be helpful:

- [If I send a message to a bad address, why don't I get a
  SendFailedException or TransportEvent indicating that the address is
  bad?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr)

I can't tell from your question what sort of error you're expecting that you're not catching.  And I can't tell why you're only looking for embedded SocketExceptions in the MessagingException.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My objective is to catch the SMTP Server Exception ... Actually, I have this Error :" Mail cannot be sent ". The Answer is that I suggest to override MailEngine class with ext-plugin (it's in util-java) to handle exceptions differently and then use it directly from the plugin instead of MailServiceUtil which only pushes all to the message bus.